# Seeing code text in bold or regular fonts

Tags: feature-request, markdown, design, code-block

Is it possible to make an option in user prefs to turn off seeing code text in bold for people who aren't used to or want to read it as a bold text?

Here's what I see in FF4 on Windows XP SP3

[image: Code block where all text is bold]

Comment: Erm, the code blocks (on SO and SU at least) already *aren't* bold... so I'm not sure where you are seeing this?

Comment: I'm seeing them in SO, haven't looked on SU. hmm, so is it just me then?

Comment: @user [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q5hEP.png) is what I see on an example code block (on WinXP FF 4.01), and a look at the CSS for that code block (via FireBug) shows no style settings to make them bold.

Comment: @DMA57361: Please see my edit in question.

Comment: I don't see bold text, but I do see comments that are in gray text.

Comment: I've also checked on my opera, I don't know whats going on :(

Comment: The example code block shown in the image above can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550#3279550), in case anyone wants to compare to the specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After zooming in a few levels (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) in Firefox it starts to look bold. Maybe you just need to reset your zoom level (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>)?

Answer (score 0):

You have Consolas font installed, and since SO stylesheet specifies it explicitly in the `font-family` chain, it gets picked up before any other. If you really want to change it, make an use of a User CSS functionality (Stylish extension for Firefox, native in Opera, I don't know about others). But it's a fine font, really (you could also remove it completely, but that's a bit of a drastic solution).

I wouldn't want the preference chain to be changed, in any case.

Comment: @DeadMG: I find it more readable than most others; it does require ClearType to look fine, though.